# Powershell - Start ordered sequence of services

Tags: windows, powershell, service, database-administration

I need to start an ordered sequence of services, i need that each service will be up and running before try to start the next one, how can I achieve this in Powershell? How can I wait for the stop too?

Thanks,

DD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a list of service names (say in an array), then foreach service:

1. Get its status
2. If not running, then start it
3. With a delay in the loop, check its status until it is running

The key is likely to be handling all the [possibilities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.ServiceProcess.ServiceControllerStatus) for #3 including the service failing.

But an outline would be something like (without handling the error cases):

```
$serviceNames | Foreach-Object -Process {
  $svc = Get-Service -Name $_
  if ($svc.Status -ne 'Running') {
    $svc.Start()
    while ($svc.Status -ne 'Running') {
      Write-Output "Waiting for $($svc.Name) to start, current status: $($svc.Status)"
      Start-Sleep -seconds 5
    }
  }
  Write-Output "$($svc.Name) is running"
}
```

`Get-Service` returns an instance of [`System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) which is "live"—indicating the current state of the service, not just the state when the instance was created.

A similar stop process would replace "Running" with "Stopped" and the "Start" call with "Stop". And, presumably, reverse the order of the list of services.

Comment: the svc object is not so live.. anyway I like this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Don't do this manually (regardless of scripting language). Define proper dependencies between the services and Windows will start/stop them in the correct order. You can use the [`sc`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754599.aspx) utility to define the dependencies:

```
sc config Svc2 depend= Svc1
```

If a service should depend on more than one other service you separate the dependent services with forward slashes:

```
sc config Svc5 depend= Svc3/Svc4
```

Note that the `=` **must** be followed by a space and **must not** be preceded by one.

Answer (score 0):

**To stop Services**

```
$ServiceNames = Get-Service | where {($_.Name -like "YourServiceNameHere*")-and ($_.Status -eq "Running")}
 Foreach-Object {$_.(Stop-Service $serviceNames)}
```

**To start Services**

```
$ServiceNames = Get-Service | where {($_.Name -like "YourServiceNameHere*")-and ($_.Status -ne "Running")}
Foreach-Object {$_.(Start-Service $ServiceNames)}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start and wait in order

```
[array]$Services = 'svc1', 'svc2', 'svc3'

$Services | foreach {
    start-service $_
    (get-service $_).WaitForStatus('Running')
}
```

The wait for status might not be needed. I have no system that have slow services to test with.

To stop and wait in order

```
[array]$Services = 'svc1', 'svc2', 'svc3'
[array]::Reverse($Services)

$Services | stop-service
```