# PowerShell - How to run a command that depends on the start of a service?

Tags: powershell

I have a script where there is an option to send an email; this requires stunnel to be running.
If the service is running and then I execute the script, it works perfectly:

```
cmd /c "blat -subject `"Test`" -body `"Test`" -ss -base64 -html -r -noh2 -to $emailto -u $username -attach $anexo -pw $password -f $username -server 127.0.0.1:25 -debug -log $blatLog"
```

But, if I try to start the service within the script it doesn't work, no errors just the email is not sent.

```
Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"
    Start-Service stunnel;
    cmd /c ""blat -subject `"Hello`" -body `"Hi`" -ss -base64 -html -r -noh2 -to $emailto -u $username -pw $password -f $username -server 127.0.0.1:25 -debug"" | Out-Null;
    Stop-Service stunnel;
`"" -Wait -Verb RunAs
```

The script do many things and none requires admin to run, except starting the service.
I know I could keep the service running, but why is it not working?

Comment: Perhaps it takes some time before the service is fully running. How about checking the Status before sending the email?

Comment: @lit You're right; I've just added "Start-Sleep -seconds 10;" after starting the service and now it works. Thanks!!

Comment: Just sleeping won't handle the case where the service fails to run. You should use `Get-Service` and check the `.status` of the returned object; see [`Get-Service` at Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-service?view=powershell-3.0)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Powershell - Start ordered sequence of services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18890389/powershell-start-ordered-sequence-of-services)

Comment: Note that `Start-service` is normally synchronous, so it seems that the `stunnel` service prematurely reports being up and running. `Start-Sleep` is an unreliable synchronization mechanism, so I suggest you look for a more reliable way to test if the service is ready for use; `(Get-Service stunnel).Status` may not be sufficient, however.

Comment: As an aside: You don't need `cmd /c` to invoke your `blat` command - just invoke it directly.

Comment: Updated with a solution.

Comment: Please do **not** update your question into an answer. Please respect that you are on a _Question_&_Answer_ site. It is fine if you answer your own question, but use the answer section below your question (see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, here is the solution I came up with:

```
$ScriptBlock = {
    function CheckStunnel {
        $t = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient '127.0.0.1', 25;
        while ($t.Connected -ne 'True') {
            If ((Get-Service stunnel).Status -ne 'Running') { Start-Service stunnel }
            Start-Sleep -seconds 3;
            $t = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient '127.0.0.1', 25;
        }
    }
}
Start-Process PowerShell "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command `"
    & {$ScriptBlock CheckStunnel}
    Blat -subject `"Test`" -body `"Test`" -ss -base64 -html -r -noh2 -to $emailto -u $username -attach $anexo -pw $password -f $username -server 127.0.0.1:25 -debug -log $blatLog;
    if ($LASTEXITCODE -eq 0) { Stop-Service stunnel }
`"" -Verb RunAs
```

Since the function of stunnel is to open a port, then I just have to check if the port is open.
It's working fine now.

Thank you for the help!